# How to compare two lists of objects with an assert using unittest module in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a method that returns a list of objects of a certain class (let's call that class A with attributes a,b c and the method my_method. So I get something like:

```
my_method() -> [A(a1, b1, c1), A(a2, b2, c2), A(a3, b3, c3)]
```

I want to unittest this method but I don't really know which assertion method I should use to do so.

I would like to write something like:

```
self.assertListEqual(my_method(), [A(a1, b1, c1), A(a2, b2, c2), A(a3, b3, c3)])
```

Notice, this line does not work (I get a failure for the test) because I think it does not work with objects list (only with basic type lists like number list). I get a:

```
First differing element 0
```

and a detail showing that those first objects have different adresses (which is of course normal) but it is not what I wanna compare. I just want to compare if attributes are equal (FYI, attributes a, b and c are "basic" types that is to say string or numbers)

The order of the elements does not matter. So I want to get a failure only if both lists contains effectively different elements (and not the same in a different order). I am working with Python3.

Thank you,

Comment: If the order of elements doesn't matter, compare `set`s rather than `list`s; also you don't say whether `A` implements `__eq__` (it will need that and `__hash__` for use in dictionaries and sets).

Comment: Ok, lets suppose I had that `__eq__` implemented and `__hash__` what would you suggest for unittesting my method?

Comment: ...compare set equality, `set(my_method()) == {A(...), ...}`

Comment: Yeah but I mean using unittest module, shouldn't I use methods from the unittest.TestCase class?

Comment: Then just use `assertEqual` (you don't need to use the "types" methods directly), but I'd recommend `py.test`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how to scalably implement **eq** but you could simply try this:

```
import unittest

class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b and self.c == other.c


a1, a2, a3 = ('a1', 'a2', 'a3')
b1, b2, b3 = ('b1', 'b2', 'b3')
c1, c2, c3 = ('c1', 'c2', 'c3')

def my_method():
    return [
        A(a1, b1, c1),
        A(a2, b2, c2),
        A(a3, b3, c3)
    ]

class BasicsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_list_of_objects(self):
        self.assertListEqual(my_method(), [A(a1, b1, c1), A(a2, b2, c2),  A(a3, b3, c3)])
```

However I'm not sure it's easy to parse the result if there's an actual error in my_method(), so that's just a quick and dirty solution...

Comment: Ok I combined this solution with jonrsharpe advice to use sets (so that order of elements does not matter). I implemented the __eq__ and __hash__ and it works. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

```python
actual = my_method() 
expected = [A(a1, b1, c1), A(a2, b2, c2), A(a3, b3, c3)]
self.assertListEqual(list(map(vars, expected)), list(map(vars, actual)))
```

You can apply `var` to the element of the list. 
As a side note, the correct order for the arguments of `assert()` is `(expected, actual)` and not `(actual, expected)`. The order matters because in case of test failure the error message would be wrong if the order was wrong.

Comment: How to unit test two lists with floating values?